# Non-Root User SSH Privileged Command with File Piping

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, pipe, io-redirection

I have an a SSH server where root login is disabled. I'm hoping to run a privileged command that will want input from a file I have after being executed. I'm hoping to do all without user interaction via a oneliner command or a script

There is key auth setup, so the below password is requested only for running the command.

The closest I have gotten is this
`echo "mypass" |ssh -tt user@ip "sudo specialCommand"`

The output will look like

```
mypass  
[sudo] password for user: 
specialCommand requests inputfile contents
```

mypass is printed before and also accepted for the password prompt

I have the file `commandInput` which I'm trying to pipe in after the password is accepted

I've failed with various attempts that were really just a guessing game, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `specialCommand` does not really require a tty, and you forced `ssh` to make one only for `sudo` password prompting, then another alternative is:

```bash
(echo "mypass" ; cat commandInput) | ssh user@ip "sudo -Sp '' specialCommand"
```

Option `-S` of `sudo` makes it read the password from stdin, which is coming from your `echo "mypass"` in this case, while option `-p ''` ensures no password prompt is displayed either.

Then you might want to put your password in a file alone, protected by proper permissions. This is usually better practice than to hardwire your password in a script. The command would then become:

```bash
cat passwordFile commandInput | ssh user@ip "sudo -Sp '' specialCommand"
```

In this latter case, **make sure** the password file is exactly one line with the password alone and nothing else, otherwise what comes after the password line will pollute the input for your `specialCommand`.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
(echo "mypass"; cat commandInput) | ssh -tt user@ip "sudo specialCommand"
```

---

Or, since you apparently have `sudo` access to the remote host, how about using `visudo` there to add this line to the very end of `/etc/sudoers` (*after* the existing line that grants the passworded `sudo` access to `user`)?

```
user  ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /full/path/of/specialCommand
```

This line grants user `user` (and nobody else) the permission to run `specialCommand` (and nothing else) as root without a password request. Trying to execute any other commands through `sudo` will still require a password as usual.

After this, you should be able to do simply:

```
ssh -tt user@ip "sudo specialCommand" < commandInput
```